# How to migrate docker images from private third party registry to Google artifact registry?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, containers, artifactory, google-artifact-registry

I am looking to copy docker images from a third-party registry to google cloud's artifact registry because google does not support third-party private registries. here [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers)

I worked around to pull the image from artifactory(third-party) and then push it to google cloud's artifact registry.

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The google artifact registry docs have a page on [migrating artifacts from a third-party registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/migrate-external-containers#copy).

In it, they recommend using [`gcrane`](https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/blob/main/cmd/gcrane/README.md), an extension of the `crane` command-line utility developed by google for use managing containers, with extensions specific to `gcr.io`.

From the [artifact registry docs](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/migrate-external-containers):

> The gcrane tool helps you with the copying process.
>
> Create a text file `images.txt` in Cloud Shell with the names of the images
> you identified. For example:
>
> ```
> ubuntu:18.04
> debian:buster
> hello-world:latest
> redis:buster
> jupyter/tensorflow-notebook
> ```
>
> Download gcrane.
>
> ```sh
> github.com/google/go-containerregistry/cmd/gcrane
> ```
>
> Create a script named copy_images.sh to copy your list of files.
>
> ```sh
> #!/bin/bash
>
> images=$(cat images.txt)
>
> if [ -z "${AR_PROJECT}" ] then
>     echo ERROR: AR_PROJECT must be set before running this
>     exit 1
> fi
>
> for img in ${images} do
>     gcrane cp ${img} LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/${AR_PROJECT}/${img}
> done
> ```
>
> Replace `LOCATION` with the `region` or `multi-region` of your
> repository.
>
> Make the script executable:
>
> ```sh
> chmod +x copy_images.sh
> ```
>
> Run the script to copy the files:
>
> ```sh
> AR_PROJECT=${PROJECT}
> ./copy_images.sh
> ```

The docs provide additional guidance on identifying images you need in your workflow, verifying permissions and updating manifests, costs, and more.

Comment: Thanks, Micheal for the answer.
I went over the doc. the problem in my case is that Artifactory is also private. gcrane can copy images that are already present in the system or pulled down. 

it's the weird use I have.

Comment: yeah - I mean I don't think your use case is that weird. but as far as I know there's no service analagous to Google Transfer Service which can accept your credentials to a 3rd party registry then does a managed transfer-as-a-service for you. If you have a very large number/size of images it may be faster to do this from within a VM in the same location as your new artifact registry. But yeah I don't think the workload you've described that you're using is that bad. Just annoying :)